# Code generator error: There is no entity type on DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want to create simple ASP.NET Core App. But when I'm trying to generate API Controller for my model I'm getting following error: 
(Screen shots presents code for model class and db context, below is code for EntityBase class)

[image: Setting up code scaffolding properties]

[image: Error]

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public EntityBase()
    {
        Created = DateTime.Now;
        Modified = Created;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you're using modified as an audit trail, it will fail you very quickly. You may want to use an alternative method.

Comment: In my case, the use of user secrets was my issue. [https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/305](https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/305)

Comment: I am currently having the same exact issue, but as you answered your own question; neither your answer nor any of the others has helped solve my problem. That is because I neither have any Many-to-Many, the key isn't the issue; and I can get it to scaffold if I use the ApplicationDbContext, but not my own custom class that uses DbContext

Comment: @Edward can you share your code? Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Can you share your code for DbContext. It's hard to find what can be wrong without looking.

Comment: I finally was able to find the issue with scaffolding my models that were created from database-first approach. The DdContext class constructor, that takes the overloaded parameter of DbContextOptions, was not present after using Scaffold-DbContext in Package Manager Console. As there was nothing wrong with Keys or relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found what was causing this error. I created Many to Many relationship between Convent and Group without using third class. I used to use fluent api to do that.

Thanks all for help!

Comment: what did you do to fix it?

Comment: I have one but still getting the error must be something else.  Thanks

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core? Can you show your code?

Comment: actually just got it to scaffold. Had to have default constructor with connection string to database. ```public MyDbContext()
            : base(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>().UseSqlServer("<connectionstring>").Options)``` to use mvc scaffolding without errors

Comment: There's no actual answer here?

Comment: There is. Entity Framework Core doesn't create "many to many" relationship automatically like EF 6 used to do. You need to manually create third object to hold two "one to many" relationships.

Comment: I have this error and have no "many to many" so your solution may have only been a stop-gag. 
@jsturtevant I tried your suggestion and it does nothing, besides if you read it should be in the [startup.cs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db) and the actual connection string should be in the appsettings.json file now.

Answer (score 1):

Having had the same issue as the title mentioned, but without any key or relationship issue, I finally found a solution to this issue. Particularly with scaffolding controllers/views from model classes that were created by a database-first approach. In your DbContext class you **MUST HAVE** the class constructor that takes the `DbContextOptions<MyDb>` parameter, which for some reason does not get added with the 'Scaffold-DbContext' command in the Package Manager Console (with an ASPNETCORE project)

```
public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public virtual DbSet<MyModel> MyModel { get; set; }
}
```

For others as well there needs to be the connection string in the appsettings.json file, and the following code in the ConfigureServies method of the file startup.cs add:

```
se‌​rvices.AddDbContext<‌​MyDbContext>(opt‌​ions => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbContection")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `[Key]` property resolves the issue when there there are no Many to Many relationships and no PRIMARY KEYs in classes

Comment: Adding an ID variable to the models fixed this error.

Comment: did nothing for me. I neither have a many-to-many, and standard int or string ID will be assumed as the Key anyways

Answer (score -1):

In my case the reason was in calling `dbContext.Database.Migrate()` inside `Startup.Configure()`. Error disapeared when I removed it.